# std::pair, how to initialize a "reference member"?

Tags: c++

In the book [C++ Move Semantics - The Complete Guide](http://www.cppmove.com/), CH8.2, there is a case that we need to create a `std::pair` object with a "reference member", and I just don't know how to create such an object. Please help.

[image]

I have tried this, but get compile error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

std::pair<std::string, std::string&> foo()
{
    static std::string s_s1{ "the~static" };
    return std::make_pair(std::string("abc"), s_s1); // compile ERROR!
}

int main()
{
    extern std::pair<std::string, std::string&> foo(); // note: member second is reference
    std::vector<std::string> coll;
    // ...
    coll.push_back(foo().first); // moves because first is an xvalue here
    coll.push_back(foo().second); // copies because second is an lvalue her
    return 0;
}
```

VC2019 spouts error message:

```
>  cl /EHsc p131.cpp 
>
> Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.29.30138 for x64 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
> 
> p131.cpp 
>
> p131.cpp(8): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from
> **'std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>'** to **'std::pair<std::string,std::string &>'** 
>
> p131.cpp(8): note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
> resolution was ambiguous
```

Comment: You can use list-initialization: `return { "abc", s_s1 };`

Comment: Your mistake is using `std::make_pair`.  That function will not correctly guess that you want one element to be a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that any templated function without explicit template types, will deduce the types from its arguments. Because `s_s1` is a `std::string`, an lvalue, that will be its deduced type.

If you explicitly use the correct types for the template types it will work:

```
return std::pair<std::string, std::string&>(std::string("abc"), s_s1);
```

Since we must name the types anyway, the `std::make_pair` convenience function isn't really needed, so I used `std::pair` directly above.